# Javascript cookie path not working as expected on iOS. Appears to be set per page

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie with javascript which is valid for a whole domain. This works everywhere except on iOS where the cookie becomes valid only for the page it was set on. For example cookie set via mydomain.com/cat/123 is not found when trying to fetch it on mydomain.com/cat/338

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (7*24*60*60*1000));
expires = d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'abc_rem=true;' +  ' expires=' + expires +'; domain=mydomain.se; path=/';
```

The problem appears in both Safari and Chrome on iOS. I have tried searching for answers to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you could try is placing a dot before the domain, like `domain=.mydomain.se;`. Don't know if it will help you though.

Comment: Thanks Michel I tried that but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled cookies on iOS? I heard that iOS has pretty restrictive setting by default, see [facebook note](https://www.facebook.com/notes/national-rail-enquiries/turning-on-cookies-in-ios-safari/10150644536327287).

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on iOS6. Can you provide more info, and maybe add the code you use for reading the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
function setCookie() {
    var c_name = "abc_rem";
    var value = "true", exdays = 365;
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    var c=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";path=/";
    document.cookie=c;
}
```

And this is how I get the cookie afterwards

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    var found = false;
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        // do whatever you need to do here
    }
}
```